# extract a letter from a string in processing

Tags: arduino, processing

im trying to get a letter from a string in processing
so lets say the sketch receives the string "x193" it would need to be able to isolate the x and the 193 and put them in different variables.

Comment: Do you know the length of the string ahead of time? You could just use substring functions if the string format is always the same.

Comment: it would vary from 2 characters long ie: x0, x2, x4 to four characters long ie: x320, x490 etc and anything in between

Comment: so is there anything i can do or not

Comment: Well if the letter is always at the beginning of your string, just use the substring() function.

Here's a link: http://www.processing.org/reference/String_substring_.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to get and put the 'x' as it is always the same, so just get what is after it, until the end of the string. Something like:

```
String[] a = {"x1", "x12", "x123"};

String[] onlyNumbers = new String[3];

void setup(){
  for (int i = 0; i length; i++){
    String stirp = a[i].substring(a[i].indexOf('x')+1, a[i].length());
    onlyNumbers[i] = stirp;
  }
  println(onlyNumbers);
}
```

If you need performance you can also use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html), wich is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

String inQuestion = "x193";

String myCharacter = inQuestion.substring(0, 1);

See http://www.processing.org/reference/String_substring_.html